# Do deer have the ability to be predators of large animals?

Tags: deer

Although it has been established that many animals formerly thought of as exclusively herbivores actually will eat meat, the examples of deer eating meat have seemed to be small animals like birds or frogs or eating from an already dead carcass. I suspect in that case the meat is already soft from decay.

I wonder if deer, even if they managed to kill a larger animal -- for example, I saw a doe defend its young by trampling a friendly dog but there was no indication whatsoever that the doe intended to eat the dog -- could successfully remove meat from a fresh kill? Perhaps deer and other mostly-herbivorous animals simply lack the dentition to do this -- fresh meat might be too tough for a deer while carnivores use their teeth as part of the killing process and are then able to eat the relatively tough raw meat of a fresh kill.

Comment: It's about their teeth, as well as their digestive system. You have answered your own question.

Comment: The drive to defend their young even at the possible expense of being injured is quite different from risking exposure to injury to gain access to meat that is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Deer will scavenge small dead animals on occasion, as you noted in your question, and can be very defensive, but they are absolutely not predators.

They also have the teeth of a herbivore, not a carnivore, so are not able to pierce or strip flesh.

Comment: The teeth, the eyes, the ears, the legs... Nothing about them says "omnivore".

Comment: @Drew I'd think the same of horses, and yet I've seen a video of on following a baby chicken around and then eating it.  So, I wouldn't *fully* say that traditional "herbivore" animals won't eat meat.

Comment: @fyrepenguin: Sure, the categories are not black-&-white. Also interesting, on predator+prey combination: https://aeon.co/essays/horse-human-cooperation-is-a-neurobiological-miracle

Comment: opportunistic behaviour is very different to predatory

Comment: Sure, but it would seem to me that the question is about ability rather than desire to be a predator. It’s a given that they can kill, so really the latter half of this answer is all that is relevant. Part of the question is whether they’d be able to consume an animal that they’d already killed, after all. But it’s plausible that they’d only be able to do that for small enough animals (like baby birds, frogs, and the like)